# A question about oversets in an equation

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, fontsize, overset

```
\overset{x = u^2}{=}
```

produces an equal sign with `x = u^2` above it in a slightly smaller font size.

If I want to add `y = v^2` above `x = u^2` but with exactly the same font size, how do I do that? `\overset{\overset{y = v^2}{x = u^2}}{=}` does not work since `y = v^2` becomes even smaller.

In addition to that, if possible, I would like all the equal signs to be displayed above each other symmetrically and not a bit to the left or right of each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you may be looking for the `\substack` command to "stack" `y=v^2` above `x=u^2`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\overset{\substack{y=v^2\\x=u^2}}{=} \quad \overset{x=u^2}{=}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

Two Addenda: (i) To align the `=` symbols, use a few `\phantom`s. (ii) A slight [!] improvement is available by reducing the size of the overset material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\xxx{\phantom{{}^2}} % a phantom that's as wide as a superscript "2"
\begin{document}

\[
\overset{\substack{\xxx y=v^2\\ \xxx x=u^2}}{=} \quad 
\overset{ \xxx x=u^2}{=}
\]

\[
\overset{\substack{\scriptscriptstyle\xxx y=v^2\\[-1pt] \scriptscriptstyle\xxx x=u^2}}{=} 
\quad\overset{\scriptscriptstyle \xxx x=u^2}{=}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You got first. I didn't want to show the picture, I felt it was terrible even without seeing it.

Comment: This is a good answer. I dunno about you, but I feel like the offsetting of the equals sign, caused by the right hand side being wider than the left hand side, is a bit imperfect. Would it be possible to have all the = signs centred wrt each other?

Comment: @Au101 - I just posted an addendum to show how one might align the = symbols. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much Mico, I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi all! I just noticed that my daily rep count for today is at 305 -- a new all-time daily record for me! Thanks so much, everyone, for upvoting and/or accepting my answers!!!!

Comment: @Mico Thanks, I think that looks a little nicer :) And well done on all of that rep! :)

Answer (score 4):

Done here with stacks and TABstacks.  Vertical gaps from primary eqn (set here as 6pt) and between secondary eqns (set as 1pt) can be customized.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\TABstackMath
\TABstackMathstyle{\scriptstyle}
\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
y \stackon[6pt]{{}={}}{\alignstackon[1pt]{\mkern8mu x =& u^2}{y =& v^2}} mx + b
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

A similar rendition may be obtained with

```
\[
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\setstackgap{S}{1pt}
y \stackon[6pt]{{}={}}{\mkern7mu\alignShortstack{y =& v^2\\ x =& u^2}} mx + b
\]
```